# Manage tasks progressions in one user interface

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, progress-bar, task-parallel-library

I have an application in witch the user can start tasks, heavy tasks.  And I want to manage the progression of these tasks in one user interface Grid (each row is a task, with a progression bar) the user can show this grid by clicking a button (using the main thread). The problem that I have is a **Cross Thread Operation**. I know why: whenever the task progression changed (with thread1), the algorithm try to update the grid datasource (with the main thread). But I don't know how to fix it.

The DataSource property of my grid is set to a `BindingList<BackgroundOperation>`.

***The definition of my task (BackgroundOperation)***

```
public class BackgroundOperation
{
    public int progression;
    public int Progression
    {
        get { return progression;}
        set
        {
            progression = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Progression");
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler OnRun;
    public event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> OnProgressChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void Run()
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            if (OnRun != null)
                OnRun(this, null);
        });

    task.Start();
    }

    public void ReportProgress(int progression)
    {
        Progression = progression;

        if (OnProgressChanged != null)
            OnProgressChanged(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs { Progression = progression });
    }


    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to .NET4.0 or even .NET4.5+? You are not using TPL here, although I would suggest that you do...

Comment: you want the main thread and main thread only to handle UI. That means that you must find a way for thread1 to signal a change on a given progression, and main to catch that signal and update display. A usual technique is to to have an event queue, to which each thread will produce/consume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the `OnProgressChanged` (which BTW should be called just `ProgressChanged`) on the UI thread. You can do that by saving [the current `SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) when the class is created and then `Post()`ing the delegate there:

```
public class BackgroundOperation
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext m_synchronizationContext;

    public BackgroundOperation()
    {
        m_synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    …

    public void ReportProgress(int progression)
    {
        Progression = progression;

        var handler = OnProgressChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            m_synchronizationContext.Post(
                _ => handler(
                    this,
                    new ProgressChangedEventArgs { Progression = progression }),
                null);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works just like it should be. Thank you very much for your help. (+1 for the SynchronizationContext class).